# comparing the i from loop with the next value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a small program that return the longest word in a sentence in javascript, I just don't understand why this error messages keeps popping up: 
    "TypeError: sen_arr[(i + 1)] is undefined."

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
var sen_arr = sen.split(" ");
for (var i = 0 ; i < sen_arr.length; i++ ) { 
   var longest = sen_arr[i];
   if (sen_arr[i].length >= sen_arr[i + 1].length) {
        longest = sen_arr[i + 1];
    } else {
        longest = sen_arr[i];
    }
 } 

return longest; 

}

LongestWord("Argument goes here");
```

if sen_arr is defined and i is defined then why sen_arr[i+1] is not?

Ps: I am just a newbie, correct me if my logic or algorithm is wrong.

Comment: For this input string: `"Foo"` that consists of a single word, what would be the "next word"?

Comment: use `for (var i = 0 ; i < sen_arr.length - 1; i++ )` in your for-loop, you are grabbing something like this: `sen_arr.length[i + 1]` so at the end, or if the array is only one word, it will be undefined.

Comment: Your idea of comparing only adjacent elements is not correct. Consider 'verylonglong', 's', 's', 's', 'ss', 's', 's'. -- Assuming that you didn't attempt to index past the end of the array, in the final iteration you would compare the final two elements 's' and 's' and then conclude that one of them is longest. Clearly 'verylonglong' is the longest element. You need to ensure that you remember what the longest element you've encountered so far is, and compare with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you logic is not correct to get longest word.Also you should declare `var longest` outside the `for loop` ,if not ,it will initialize new value when next looping.You get undefined is as array key is doesn't exist in `sen_arr` because you are using +1 so if `i` is 2 will become 3.That's what u get undefined error.

`sen_arr` after split is `[0=>Argument,1=>goes,2=>here]` // key 3 is not exist

[function 1]

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
var sen_arr = sen.split(" ");
var longest;//declare here
for (var i = 0 ; i < sen_arr.length; i++ ) { 
   /*var*/ longest = sen_arr[i]; //shouldn't declare here
   (i < 2) ?  j = i+1 : j = i;   //do +1 if i is less than 2 
   if (sen_arr[i].length >= sen_arr[j].length) {
        longest = sen_arr[j];
    } else {
        longest = sen_arr[i];
    }
 } 

return longest; 

}
```

[function 2]

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
   var sen_arr = sen.split(" "),longest = 0,index;
   for (var i = 0 ; i < sen_arr.length; i++ ) {    
    if(longest < sen_arr[i].length) {
      longest = sen_arr[i].length;
      index = i;
    }  
 }  
 longest = sen_arr[index];
 return longest;     
}
LongestWord("Argument goes here");          //return Argument
LongestWord("Argument goes hereherheherhe");//return hereherheherhe
```

> > Note: function 1 is not correct to get longest word,But function 2 is correct

Answer (score 0):

Longest word in a sentence

```
function longWord(senten){

      var arraysize = senten.split(" ");

        console.log(arraysize.length);
       var arr=[];
      for(let i = 0;i<arraysize.length;i++){
        arr.push(arraysize[i].length);
        }
      console.log(arr);
      console.log(Math.max.apply(null, arr)); 
        var final;
        for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
         if(Math.max.apply(null, arr)==arr[i]){
           final = arraysize[i];

         }
        }
       return final;

    }
    console.log(longWord("How are u friends welcome to javascript Program"));
```

Comment: While this function might work, it doesn't answer the question that was asked. Can you provide rationale and explanation?